# how to insert and save image in mysql database using matlab

Tags: mysql, database, matlab

I am working in my project and i have some question 
how to insert ( image and any file of type .dat ) to mysql database table using matlab and how i can show it after saved in database .the code I used

```
   cd('C:\Users\Esra\`Documents`\MATLAB\finaltest')

[templatefile,pathname]=uigetfile('*.dat','open file ');%matrix of feature
if templatefile~= 0
  cd(pathname);
    z=load (char(templatefile));
end;
inser(con,'new_table',{'id','job','FFP'},{'11','admin',z});%FFP feature of fingerprint
```

error

```
operands to the || and && operands must be convertible to logical scalar values
```

and thanks

Comment: Looks like `inser` should be `insert`.  Which statement causes the error?

Comment: Where in your code do you use `||` and `&&`?

Comment: macduff .yes it is insert but I jest made a mistake when writing the question

Comment: Schorsch .no i did not use

Comment: and after store image in database how i can read image